# SQL usando LIKE dentro de una variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, if

Buenas amigos quiero saber como usar **like** dentro de una variable para saber si existen los números **6,7,8** . Alguien sabe cual sería la sintaxisis correcta para este caso?

```
@listaMenus  = '4,5,6,7,8,9,10'

if (@listaMenus like '%8%' or  '%6%')
begin
  print 'no puedo continuar'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más cercano a lo que solicitas es utilizando la funcion CHARINDEX.

Utilizando el mismo ejemplo que mencionas, tendríamos lo siguiente

```
DECLARE @listaMenus VARCHAR(50) = '4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
IF CHARINDEX('8', @listaMenus)>0 OR CHARINDEX('6', @listaMenus)>0
BEGIN
  PRINT 'no puedo continuar'
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Una forma interesante es "expander" la lista separada por comas, en una tabla de valores:

```
DECLARE @ListaMenus VARCHAR(255)

SELECT  @ListaMenus = '4,5,6,7,8,9,10'

SELECT  Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Valor
    FROM  (
        SELECT  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@ListaMenus, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Valores  
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Valores.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Básicamente convertimos `@ListaMenus` en un [XML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) para luego expandir cada elemento en una nueva fila. El resultado sería algo así:

```
Valor
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Y ahora nada nos impide hacer un `IN` sobre esta tabla, por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Existe     INT
SELECT  TOP 1 @Existe = Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
    FROM  (
        SELECT  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@ListaMenus, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Valores  
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Valores.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
    WHERE CONVERT(INT,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) IN (6, 7, 8)

IF @Existe IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    PRINT 'Existe!!!'
END
```

**Importante**: esta solución es válida únicamente a partir de SQL 2008